# Django queries: how to make contains OR not_contains queries

Tags: python, django

I have to make a query that will get records containing "wd2" substring or not containing "wd" string at all. Is there any way to do it nicely?

Seems something like:

`Record.objects.filter( Q(parameter__icontains="wd2") | Q( ## what should be here? ## ) )`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the django [q object documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> You can compose statements of arbitrary complexity by combining Q objects with the & and | operators and use parenthetical grouping. Also, Q objects can be negated using the ~ operator, allowing for combined lookups that combine both a normal query and a negated (NOT) query:

```
Q(question__startswith='Who') | ~Q(pub_date__year=2005)
```

So I would recommend

```
Record.objects.filter( Q(parameter__icontains="wd2") | ~Q(parameter__icontains="wd") )
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about ~ operator. Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't it elegant?  I love reusing low-level logic ideas in a higher level composition paradigm!